# jQuery .on delegated mouseenter mouseleave not working

Tags: jquery

It will work on the first dynamic created link, but it won't work on the other links. Also, the popup information is already shown before it hovers for some reason. This is what i have:

```
<div id="parent">
<a href="" id="hovertitle">Hover Text</a>
</div>

<div id="popup">
    testing 123
</div>
```

This is my jfiddle including the jquery link http://jsfiddle.net/2XG9j/1/ 
It works on the jfiddle, but when I run it with my dynamic objects it doesn't work for the other links.

Comment: _"but when I run it with my dynamic objects it doesn't work for the other links"_ Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that because i'm using jdbc to retrieve dynamic objects from mysql.

Comment: First guess without full code, IDs must be unique. change `id="parent"` to `class="parent"` and the selector to `.parent`.

Comment: Have not tried jdbc . There appears to be single element having an `id` referenced inside event handlers.

Comment: So changing to class=parent works, BUT now when i hover over each individual element, the other elements display the popup information all together, instead of individually.

Comment: _"So changing to class=parent works, BUT now when i hover over each individual element, the other elements display the popup information all together, instead of individually."_ Can you update the jsfiddle link to demonstrate this ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2XG9j/4/  It's something like this, but i don't want to create multiple JS scripts for each different div class. how can i make one js script but for unique div elements? @guest271314

Comment: @evelyn http://jsfiddle.net/2XG9j/5/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 how can i make it autohide on default ? and hide when mouse leaves rather than still showing it?

Comment: @evelyn Set `display:none` for elements where `className` begins with `"popup"` at `css` ; see post

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.next()` , `.toggle()` ; setting `display:none` for elements where `className` begins with `"popup"` at `css` ; attaching events to selector `"[class^=parent]"` , elements where `className` begins with `"parent"`

```js
$(document)
.on("mouseenter", "[class^=parent]", function(e) {
  $(this).next("[class^=popup]").toggle()
})
.on("mouseleave", "[class^=parent]", function(e) {
  $(this).next("[class^=popup]").toggle()
});
```

```css
div[class^="parent"] {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding 4px;
}
div[class^="popup"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="parent">
  <a href="" id="hovertitle">Hover Text</a>
</div>

<div class="popup">
  test
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <a href="" id="hovertitle">Hover Text</a>
</div>

<div class="popup2">
  test 2
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2XG9j/5/

---

Note, given `html` at Question, expected results can also be achieved using `css` `:hover` , next sibling `+` selector , without utilizing `javascript`

```css
div[class^="parent"] {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding 4px;
}
div[class^="popup"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: none;
}
div[class^="parent"]:hover + div[class^="popup"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="" id="hovertitle">Hover Text</a>
</div>

<div class="popup">
  test
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <a href="" id="hovertitle">Hover Text</a>
</div>

<div class="popup2">
  test 2
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2XG9j/6/

Comment: This seems to be working on a static HTML, but not for dynamic for some reason

Comment: _"This seems to be working on a static HTML, but not for dynamic for some reason "_ Can you describe "but not for dynamic" ? create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?